# Find the shortest subarray in an array, whose sum of indexes in the given array equals the sum of the elements of the subarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion, array-algorithms

I'm almost a beginner programmer that wants to learn how to write algorithms.I just wrote a program that finds the **shortest** subarray(subset) in an array, whose sum of indexes in the given array equals the sum of the elements of the subarray(subset) and prints out the sum.
The problem is, I needed to keep track of both the amount of numbers in the subarray(to find the shortest one) as well as the sum of the chosen elements(because I want to save it or just print it), so I would like to return a 2-element array recursively, but any way I try it, I end up having an error like "NoneType is not subscriptable" or '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'.
So I used a global variable and solved it that way. But how do I avoid using a global variable in this type of problem? Here is my code, please teach me how to solve this type of problem without a global variable:

```
best_sum = math.inf

def SumIndexesEqualSumElements(T, idx=0, idxsum=0, tabsum=0, count=0):
    global best_sum
    if idx==len(T):
        if count==0:
            return math.inf
        if idxsum==tabsum:
            best_sum = tabsum
            return count
        return math.inf
    return min(SumIndexesEqualSumElements(T,idx+1,idxsum+idx,tabsum+T[idx],count+1),
               SumIndexesEqualSumElements(T,idx+1,idxsum,tabsum,count))

SumIndexesEqualSumElements([1,7,3,5,11,2])
print(best_sum)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is finding **subset** of the array having equal indices sum.

I suggest you to solve beginner level - **subarray** and **subset** question. Than, come to this.

For this question, you can brute force array, finding all the subarray sums and indices sum. Then, selecting the best one -  **shortest**(here)

```
def SumIndexesEqualSumElements(arr):
    best_length = len(arr)
    ans_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        indices_sum = 0
        elements_sum = 0
        length = 0
        for j in range(i,len(arr)):
            indices_sum += j
            elements_sum += arr[j]
            length += 1
            if indices_sum == elements_sum:
                if length < best_length:
                    best_length = length
                    ans_sum = elements_sum
    return ans_sum
print(SumIndexesEqualSumElements([1,3,3,0,11,2]))
```

using 0 - based Indexing

Comment: I meant to consider all subsets of the array, not necessarily consecutive elements. Thank you for your effort though.